# Probability of choosing correct coin

Tags: probability

I have 3 coins. Two have $P(heads)=p$ and one is two headed ($P(heads)=1$). If I toss them all and choose a coin that is heads, what is the probability that I have chosen the two headed coin?

......

Comment: You mean you randomly uniformly choose a coin that is heads among all coins that are heads?

Comment: @joriki Ya! [15]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result is $HHH$ (happens with probability $p^2$), you select the two headed coin with probability $\frac13$. If the result is $HHT$ (happens with probability $2p(1-p)$), you select it with probability $\frac12$. If the result is $HTT$ (happens with probability $(1-p)^2$), you surely select it.
In total, the probability is
$$ \frac13p^2+\frac12\cdot 2p(1-p) + (1-p)^2=1-p+\frac13p^2.$$